# Proofs with axioms for natural numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, axioms, natural-numbers

I just started a course in discrete mathematics and i am totally stuck on something basic.

Construct proofs of the following rules using only axioms for natural numbers:

$1 * n = n$ and $(a+b)*c = ac + bc$

I don't need the solutions. 
Is there any specific methodology to solve that kind of problems?

EDIT:
Axioms list:

1) a + b

2) a x b

3) a + b = b + a

4) (a + b) + c = a + (b + c)

5) a x b = b x a

6) (a x b) x c = a x (b x c)

7) if m x z = n x z then m = n

8) There is a special element of N, denoted by 1, which has the property that n x 1 for all n as natural numbers.

9) a * (b + c) = (a * b) + (a * c)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider mathematical induction

Comment: It depends on what your axioms are.

Comment: It might be good to mention what exact list of axioms you are using. Also, I think you made a typo in the second statement. That should be $ac + bc$, right?

Comment: @MarkKamsma Added the list of axioms, corrected the typo. Thanks.

Comment: $a +b$ and $a \times b$ aren't axioms.

Comment: @RobertShore According to the book, they are.

Comment: Then there's a problem.  Is there some kind of definition for $a+b$ and $a \times b$?  Perhaps using the Successor function to build up $a+b$ and then induction to build up $a \times b$?

Comment: @RobertShore It states that the first two axioms are just showing that the addition and multiplication can be performed for natural numbers a and b.

Comment: There has to be more than that.  Otherwise addition and multiplication can be any arbitrary commutative and associative operations such that multiplication is $1-1$ on either component.  For example, how do you know $\exists a, b ~ a+b \neq 0$?

Comment: You have a typo in 9, the last + should be *.  Your statement of 8 is incomplete.  You list $n*1$ but do not say $n*1=n$, which is what you need

Comment: Math is very precise.  Probably axioms 1 and 2 are that addition and multiplication are closed, that whatever naturals you add or multiply you get another natural, which you have omitted.  In many expositions, the naturals are defined as a set plus two operations and the definition of operation includes closure.  As you have shown them, they are useless because we don't know what a+b implies.  Reading math is a different skill from normal reading, which you need to work on.  8 and 9 should have struck you as essential, not as almost what you are asked to prove.

Comment: " 8 and 9 should have struck you as essential, not as almost what you are asked to prove" commutativity is so basic That being told tht $n*1 = n$ is an axiom and being asked to prove $1*n = n$, I think a student can be forgiven for not immediately seeing that the are actually different statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can't prove the first because you are not given that there is an element called $1$ or one that functions as one unless that is part of the definition of multiplication.  Note that the even naturals satisfy all your axioms but there is no $1$.  Similarly, you have nothing to link addition and multiplication, so you can't prove the distributive law.  We can just interchange addition and multiplication with your axioms and the distributive law fails.

If you write the added axioms correctly, you are all set.  $8$ must be $n*1=n$, so you just apply $5$ to that to get $1*n=n$.  For the second, you start with $9$ and apply $5$, then rename $a,b,c$.

Comment: Added two more axioms that are stated in the book.
I did not added them from the beginning cause they are basically what is requested to prove

Comment: No, that aren't what is requested to prove.  The are written in reverse order so you must apply Axiom 5 (multiplication is commutative)

Answer (score 0):

Axiom 5 tells you that $1*n =n*1$ and Axiom 8 tells you $n*1 = n$

And Axiom 5 tells yoou that

$(a+b)*c = c*(a+b)$ and axiom 9 tells you $c*(a+b) = c*a +c*b$ and axiom 5 tells you $c*a + c*b = a*c + b*c$.